# Undefined Method in HTTParty class

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, image, api, httparty

I'm somewhat new to rails and every time I think I'm getting it I hit a wall.

I'm using `HTTParty` and this [API](http://snapito.com/paid-api.jsp). I am just trying to get a response to show up in my index view to get the lowest level of the api working.

It worked for me in the console but not when I tested it in the API. I'm getting an

```
undefined method `picture' for Snapshots:Class
```

error for my index view.

Here is the HTTParty class

```
class Snapshots
  include HTTParty

  def initialize
    @sitename = "google.com"
  end

  def picture
    response = HTTParty.get("http://api.snapito.com/web/516e011353b62078731712566b01e143f56adf0b/full/diditmatter.herokuapp.com/lists")

    if respone.success?
      response
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my lists controller

```
def index
    @it_works = Snapshots.picture

    respond_with(@lists = List.all)
end
```

And here is list view

```
<%= @it_works %>


<h1 class="page-header">Projects at a glance</h1> 
<div class="span12 offset2"> 
 <% @lists.each do |list| %> 
  <div class="well row span4">
    <div class="span3">
    </div>  
    <div class="span4">
```

What do I seem to be overlooking here?

EDIT

@Benjamin fix worked, but I've come across a problem I'm not sure is related to rails. I'm not sure is I should open another question. But since the context is here and I'm not really even sure how to search this, I have to follow up here.

That instance variable is returning the attached screen shot. Is this related to how I'm calling it from the API I linked to in the first paragraph?

[image]I've never seen this so not to sure where to look or how to approach.

Comment: Ah. You are trying to display the picture in binary. See if this helps: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are treating the `picture` method as a class method. Change it to this: `@it_works = Snapshots.new.picture`

Comment: This worked and is considered resolved but it seems I have another problem I'm not even sure how to tackle unrelated. Thanks.